# jquery .post send email using swiftmailer

Tags: php, jquery, post, email-attachments, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an email using swiftmailer(for attachments) and I have been using in the past the following jquery post code:

```
$.post("contact.php", $("#contact").serialize());
```

this use to work fine, but now for some reason it stopped working when making the switch to swiftmailer..If I have a page with action="contact.php" then it works but using the jquery post function seems not to..

here's the complete jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact").submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $( this );
    var nombre = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val();
    var apellido = $form.find( 'input[name="apellido"]' ).val();
    var phone = $form.find( 'input[name="telefono"]' ).val();
    var email = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val();
    var jobtitle = $form.find( 'input[name="jobtitle"]' ).text();
    //var filesize = $form.find('input[name="file"]').files[0].size;
    if(nombre == "")
    {   
        $("#result").empty().append("Please fill in required fields.");
        $("#result").css('color','Red');                
        $('#name').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(apellido == "")
    {   
        $("#result").empty().append("Please fill in required fields.");
        $("#result").css('color','Red');                
        $('#apellido').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(email == "")
    {   
        $("#result").empty().append("Please fill in required fields.");
        $("#result").css('color','Red');                
        $('#email').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if( !isValidEmailAddress(email) ) { 
        $("#result").empty().append("invalid email.");
        $("#result").css('color','Red');                
        $('#email').focus();
        return false;
        }
    }
    if(phone == "")
    {   
        $("#result").empty().append("Please fill in required fields.");
        $("#result").css('color','Red');                
        $('#phone').focus();
        return false;
    }
    //if(filesize <= 0)
    //{
    //  $("#result").empty().append("Please attach your resume.");
       //   $("#result").css('color','Red');                
      //    $('#file').focus();
     // return false;
    //}
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
   //event.preventDefault(); 
   $.post("contact.php", $("#contact").serialize());
   $("#contact").attr('style', 'display:none');
   $("#result").empty()
   $("#success").empty().append("<h2>Thank you, we will review your information and contact you as soon as possible.</h2>");
   $("#success").css('color','#000');
   $("#success").attr('style', 'display:block');
   return false;
});

});
```

and my php file "contact.php" has this:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$title = $_POST['jobtitle'];

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

// Give the message a subject
->setSubject('Nuevo applicante para: ' . $title)

// Set the From address with an associative array
->setFrom(array('no-reply@email.com' => 'no-reply'))

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo('destination@email.com')

// Give it a body
->setBody('<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Nombre:</td><td>' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellido .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Email:</td><td>' . $email . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Telefono:</td><td>'. $telefono .'</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>', 'text/html')

 // Optionally add any attachments
 ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])
 ->setFilename($_FILES['file']['name']));

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

?>
```

Here are test links:

with jquery post: [here](http://inblu.pe/topitop/opportunities/publicacion-de-prueba/) (click on "Apply" and a popup should appear)

just php: [here](http://inblu.pe/topitop/opportunities/test.php)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? The server doesn't respond to the AJAX call?  The AJAX call responds with success code but no email is sent? Have you done any debugging to try to narrow down the issue?

Comment: i get no error code, and it acts like as if it sent, but I get no email. I've updated my question to links where I'm testing

Answer (score 0):

Stop using [MailTransport](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-mail-transport).  MailTransport just calls `mail()` under the covers.

`mail()` is notoriously unreliable because most hosting providers don't bother configuring their servers sanely.

Use [SendmailTransport](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-sendmail-transport) or [SmtpTransport](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-smtp-transport) instead.  Your host surely has an SMTP server or a Sendmail installation.  Check their documentation, they should the sendmail path and information about SMTP handy.

Comment: I changed it to smtptransport but it still does the same, act as if it sends yet I get no email. but if I try without the jquery post function it sends perfectly.

Comment: That does not make any sense whatsoever.  Are you sure that there isn't some error that's happening that you aren't checking for?  Maybe an uncaught exception?